# C++ polymorphism and type casting

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am relatively new to C++ and  I have been working on a basic 3D rendering engine using OpenGL.I have the following issue:
I have a class called GeomEntity which is the base class for all geometry primitives.I have another class called DefaultMaterial which is the base class for all materials(consists of different types of shader programs) .Because I am going to have many types of materials like :ColorMaterial,TextureMaterial,AnimatedMaterial and so on I need to put a reference to the material in GeomEntity class so that from the main app I can set any of the material with this function:

```
  void GeomEntity ::addMaterial (const DefaultMaterial *mat){

         material=mat;////material is the member variable pointer of type DefaultMaterial

  }
```

But the thing is that although all of those materials are derived from the DefaultMaterial they all have got their unique methods which I can't trigger if I reference them to the variable of DefaultMaterial by default.
So for example in the main application:

```
  Sphere sphere;
  ....
  sphere.addMaterial(&animMaterial);///of type AnimatedMaterial
  sphere.material->interpolateColor(timerSinceStart);
   ///doesn't happen anything  as the sphere.material is
  /// of type DefaultMaterial that has   no interpolateColor() method
```

I know I have can use templates or casts but I would like to hear about the best practices of this kind of polymorphism in C++ .In Java or C# I would really use something like this:

```
((AnimatedMaterial)sphere.material).interpolateColor(timerSinceStart);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you can do this using dynamic_cast, that is I believe closest equivalent of that C# feature:

```
AnimatedMaterial* panim = dynamic_cast<AnimatedMaterial*>(sphere.material);
if(panim) 
  panim->interpolateColor(timerSinceStart);
```

Comment: I think this is the closest thing to what I know in the managed languages.

Comment: I agree, dynamic_cast is more adapted for polymorphism that static_cast, because it checks that the object being cast is actually of the derived class type. And it returns a null pointer if the object is not of the desired type.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast, it would look like:

```
static_cast<AnimatedMaterial*>(sphere.material)->interpolateColor(...);
```

But use Blindy's way, it's cleaner.

---

Original answer made invalid by question edit:

<strike>You said:</strike>

```
//material is the member variable pointer of type DefaultMaterial
```

Looking at the way you're using it, it's not actually a pointer.  If it were, everything would be working properly.

```
void GeomEntity::addMaterial( DefaultMaterial *mat )
{
    material = mat; // material is the member variable pointer of type DefaultMaterial*
}
```

When passing around polymorphic objects, you should be using pointers, not references.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.And the issue is not the pointer but how I trigger the methods found on the derived classes when their property data type is of the base class?

Comment: @Michael IV, I disagree, the real issue is *why do you want to do that*? A properly modeled OOP class hierarchy shouldn't care about the type of its instances, it should handle itself with only the base class as an interface.

Comment: @Blindy ,you are absolutely right.So you say I don't need to cast if the material references the right class containing that methods>?

Comment: Indeed, all you need to do with a material is to bind it to your context (ogl? d3d? something else?), so you need a virtual `Bind` function in your base class that you can call. You don't care *how* that binding occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that `sphere.material` points to an object that has `interpolateColor` method associated with it, you can use `static_cast` (if there were doubts, then you would use `dynamic_cast`). So assuming that `AnimatedMaterial` class has `interpolateColor` method:

```
static_cast<AnimatedMaterial*>(sphere.material)->interpolateColor(timerSinceStart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use:

```
Sphere sphere;
//....
sphere.addMaterial(*animMaterial);  //of type AnimatedMaterial
animMaterial->interpolateColor(timerSinceStart);
```

since `animMaterial` is already of the right type?

Comment: The material property inside the GeomEntity is of the generic DefaultMaterial type which doesn't have interpolateColor() method

Comment: @Ben Voigt, are you sure? The internal material could also be a reference (still weird, but yea..). Calling `interpolateColor` on the material itself should still work fine outside the function. @Michael, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: After the question got changed, this seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: @Blindy: Yeah, I'm sure.  If the internal material was a reference, `material = mat;` would NOT rebind the reference.  But now the question changed.

Comment: @Ben, well if one was a pointer and one a reference it wouldn't even compile, so I think we can assume their types match :)

Comment: @Blindy: Since the code is clearly not cut+pasted from the code that does compile, I'm not sure what we can assume.  A couple seconds ago the parameter `mat` was a reference.  In such a case `material = mat;` always makes a copy (by assignment, not by construction), it never forms a reference (which only occurs during initialization).